# Combine 2 queries from different tables with different fields names

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to select and retrieve results from two separate database tables and then loop them within one html table. I could do commands and name them separately, combine the results and loop through them. Is there a way of doing this with one query though?

The example below would not work, but that is the logic behind what i'd like to achieve.

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE column5 = 'YES'";
$Data = mysql_query($SQL);

$SQL = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1 = 'YES'";
$Data = mysql_query($SQL);

// loops through records displaying in table format
for($Loop = 0; $Loop < mysql_num_rows($Data); $Loop++)
{
     $Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Data);
     $Ref = $Row["Ref"];
     // rest of fields
}
```

*Note: I know mysql is deprecated. I will be moving over to pdo when I rebuild the site but for now i need to use a `mysql` function.*

Comment: Do both tables have the same number of columns?

Comment: what are the fields in your tables ?

Comment: Both tables have different number of columns and column names

Comment: If both database are on the same server you can use the notation `db_name`.`table_name`, otherwise you can specify to the mysql_query which database to use mysql_query($SQL, $con). See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696380/how-to-use-multiple-database-in-a-php-web-application

Comment: @TheApptracker , does both the tables, **`table1` and `table3`** contain **"Ref" attribute**???

Comment: @TheApptracker what do u mean by combining? do u mean combining the **resultset**?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table3 
JOIN table1 ON table3.column5=table1.column1 AND table3.column5='YES'
```

Or,change it to mysqli and use http://docs.php.net/mysqli.multi-query

Comment: mihai, does concatenation works with resource-type variables in PHP??? As per my knowledge it works with string, int, real type values.

Please clarify...

Answer (score 0):

You could have used **`UNION`** in the sql query if both the tables had same no. of attributes-

```
(SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE column5 = 'YES')
UNION
(SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1 = 'YES')
```

So use the following code snippet-

```
$SQL = "(SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE column5 = 'YES') UNION (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1 = 'YES')";
$Data = mysql_query($SQL);

// loops through records displaying in table format
for($Loop = 0; $Loop < mysql_num_rows($Data); $Loop++)
{
     $Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Data);
     $Ref = $Row["Ref"];
     // rest of fields
}
```

In that case there should be an attribute `Ref` in the 1st table specified in the `UNION` query i.e. `table3` here.